# How to consume the REST service with ajax(jQuery) in Spring Boot?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, rest, spring-boot

I'm following an official Spring doc on this topic https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/#_create_the_application_page

Maybe there's something else omitted/missing, but I can't get it working with me (Intellij, SpringBoot).

I have exactly the same Greeting(from their repo https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service/tree/master/complete/src/main/java/hello), GreetingController classes, the latter is supposed to return JSON data. Both controllers, tested apart, work well. My "index.html" and "hello.js" are also copied up to a tee.

But as far as I understand, to get it working one needs to redirect a client to this "index.html" page, so for that purpose I've added another Controller.

Finally, the complete project structure:

```
src
|--main
   |---java
       |---com.example.demo
           |---controller
               GreetingController.java
               ClientController.java
           |---model
               Greeting.java
       DemoApplication.java
  |---resources
      |---static.js
             hello.js
      |---templates
             index.html
      application.properties
```

hello.js reads as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://localhost:8080/greeting'
}).then(function(data) {
    $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
    $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
});
```

});

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello jQuery</title>

    <!--alt+enter to download the library in case it's not there-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../static/hello.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <p class="greeting-id">The ID is </p>
    <p class="greeting-content">The content is </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, hello.js has the following function:

```
url: 'https://localhost:8080/greeting'
```

As far as I see, this is supposed to access this address, and the response received will be provided by GreetingController, and then parsed as a JSON object. But I only get:

The ID is
The content is

What's wrong? The only difference with this tutorial is that I have my own usual Spring Controller instead of their Groovy one. What else do I need to get it all glued together successfully?

Comment: any errors in console? any errors server side? what happens when you go to that url?

Comment: @Janar no, no error messages. When I go to /greeting, I get a JSON string, and when I go the page with "index.html", I get just these 2 lines as they are. It seems like there is no mapping between them and the jquery result.

Comment: @downvoter What exactly is unclear to you ?

Comment: if the server side works you should try debugging the client side - use dev tools to see if the js is loaded and try debugging the function - is the function getting called, does it return the correct data etc - also, consider editing the function into the question.

Comment: I've only set a breakpoint in js file, and it did not stop there. But the file path is being recognized by the IDE. My only guess is that it is not called. I'm trying to figure out why so.

Comment: try checking dev tools (F12 on most browsers) network tab and see if the 'https://localhost:8080/greeting' is called when you go the the index page. also at dev tools you can see the console where errors go if there are any.

Comment: thanks, it was a good idea, now I see that I have an error 404:failed to load hello.js. I'll try to check why.

Comment: from the project structure you posted seems the folder is named static.js instead of static

Comment: yes, that's how IDE has renamed it itself, after I've added a js file into there. That confused me too, but now as I've renamed it back to 'static', error still remains.

Comment: please post your html code too. I am guessing the script should be loaded as
 `<script src="static/hello.js"></script>`

Comment: Sure. Updated the post with html code. This is how IDE has itself generated the path to the file inside <script>, and changes it if i move the file. When I click ctrl+enter on this path, I move right to js file correctly.

Comment: Could you try these two variants, pretty sure one of them will work:
`<script src="static/hello.js"></script>` or
`<script src="hello.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you, Janar. Fixing 2 things eventually worked: 1) src is changed to "hello.js" 2)I mistakenly had put 'https' to the localhost address, which of course should've been just 'http' in my case.
I don't know how to pick your answer as a correct one.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments it was clarified that the javascript file wasn't found. To fix that you had to

1. change script location to `<script src="hello.js"></script>` since spring boot looks for static files under src/main/resources/static by default
2. Also the url had to be http instead of https.